# Router refuses to respond to ping from WAN/Internet

Tags: networking, router, internet, ping

I have a D-Link DIR-615 X1 router, WAN is configured as Static IPv4 with no port forwarding/UPnP/DMZ configured, and I can ping from a device or router to a device, router, or internet; however, if I attempt to ping my WAN IP from a device connected to the router, it fails with error `Request timed out` *(I tried again, first with a different device connected to a different network, then with a [remote monitoring tool](https://www.wormly.com/test-remote-ping))*.

All I found on the web was something about NAT Loopback *(hence trying with a different device)* and routers not being configured to respond to ICMP echo requests.; unfortunately, I found no guides to enable this - is this the problem I'm having?

*Is this the best place for this question, or should I have put it somewhere like Serverfault?*

**UPDATE:-** After following mashuptwice's answer (enabling ping in WAN settings), I can now ping my external ip address from a device within my network, but not from outside.

Comment: 1) Did you get the public IP address from the router's own status screen, or from a "what's my IP" kind of website? 2) Is it actually a public IP address and not a 100.64.x CGNAT address? 3) Also, ping _to_ the WAN address isn't the same thing as ping _from_ WAN (this is kind of where the "NAT loopback" issue comes from)

Comment: Your router is doing the equivalent of "Shhh! I'm not here".

Comment: @user1686 1) I got it from a website. 2) It's in the form of 103.252.xx.xx 3) Yes, I pinged it from a device not connected to the router, so that counts as _from_ WAN _to_ WAN address, right?

Comment: _(Please do not post non-public WAN IPs in questions/answers, as it's a security risk for the user doing so.)_ All routers have a stateful firewall that blocks all inbound WAN traffic by default that did not originate as a new connection from the router/downstream devices _(the only exception to this I've come across is OpenWrt's default firewall config [`/etc/config/firewall`], which does allow bi-directional ICMP pings)_

Comment: @JW0914 Of course, that was just an example. And I have no rules configured in my router's firewall. I tried to configure a rule to allow ICMP connections to my router, but since my public ip address is dynamic, I have no idea what to put in the _destination ip address_ field. Just leaving it blank does nothing. As such, I am stumped. :|

Comment: @SubhoBoy I've never used the OS [firmware] your router uses, but normally allowing bi-directional ICMP pings from WAN doesn't require specifying a destination IP, just an inbound firewall zone [WAN] and some other basic information. OpenWrt's default [firewall config](https://pastebin.com/DEBRzfKz) may help you _(lines: 38 - 52, 78 - 113)_

Answer (score 1):

Page 62/63 of the [D-Link DIR-615 X1 user manual](https://manuals.plus/m/7450b16dd6d00205529d0a64430754f796f3dddb8da8a7f6c0eabb078b7c304d):

[image: settings]

```
Ping:   If the switch is moved to the right, the router responds to ping
        requests from the external network through this connection. For
        security reasons, it is recommended to disable this function
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the X1 hardware revision looks absolutely nothing like the other models, both physically and in the web interface. As such, most info about the DIR-615 found online is useless for me. Only place I found the correct details and user manual was by searching on [fcc](https://fcc.gov/fccid). The router id is KA2-IR615X1.

Comment: @SubhoBoy The manual for the X1 was also pretty easy to find. Added the instructions for your X1 model.

Comment: Updated question with current status